# Unwanted white border around canvas, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

**Edited since I forgot to add examples**

Since I started working on this game there was a white border around the canvas and I don't understand the cause of it, some people say it's because of the clearRect function but I tried it and it didn't work.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

This is the code:

**NOTE:** The canvas I'm working on is called "gameCanvas"

**--- HTML ---** *(Partial)*

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>

        <!-- OUTER ELEMENTS -->

        <div id="canvasSpace">
            
            

        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->

    <script type="module" src="./game/Main.js"></script>

</body>
```

**--- CSS ---**

*body*

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}
```

*container*

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

*gameCanvas*

```
#gameCanvas{
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    
    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**--- JavaScript ---** *(Just for precaution)*

```
function draw() //^ draw() has the purpose to ONLY draw (and also call requestAnimationFrame() to mantain the loop) on the canvas [Xavier]
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //? Clears the whole canvas space in order to print new elements over it  [Xavier]

    game.draw();

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), no party.

Comment: Your css doesn't seem to be loaded :)

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález How do I create a reproducible example if I don't know what's causing the problem?

Comment: @Kokodoko the css is loaded, for example if I change the image-rendering property it gets updated

Comment: a reproducible example is a sample of your code that shows the issue.... read the link on that minimal, reproducible example, ... the code you pasted is just disconnected pieces ... what are the context and game variables?

Comment: Let's try to dig a bit further @aka_lux. If the CSS you've posted is really all the CSS, it can't be the culprit. To narrow the issue down a bit, what happens if you get rid of the `game.draw()` - so you're essentially just clearing the canvas. If the border is gone there must be something wrong with your `draw()` method.

Comment: @aka_lux *if you read the link* it shows you how to do that. Specially the "divide and conquer" part where it exactly says "If you’re not sure what the source of the problem is" that you are complaining about. That's basic debugging skills and I'm making you learn how to debug, which is going to be very important for you in the future.